# How to determine the number of widgets contained in a sidebar via customizer JS

Tags: widgets, javascript, theme-customizer

I am trying to access a widget area in the customizer via JS with the intent of getting count of the amount of widgets in the section.

I am able to access some information with the code below but am not quite there.

```
wp.customize.section( 'sidebar-widgets-sidebar-1', function( section ) {
    console.info( section  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you *can* look at the `WidgetControl` instances contained inside of a `SidebarSection`, it is better to instead to look at the underlying `setting` that lists out the widgets contained inside of the sidebar. So do something like this:

```
wp.customize( 'sidebars_widgets[sidebar-1]', function( sidebarSetting ) {
    console.info( sidebarSetting.get().length );
} );
```

Alternatively, with a reusable function:

```
/**
 * Get the count of widgets in a given sidebar.
 * 
 * @param {string} sidebarId Sidebar ID.
 * @returns {jQuery.promise} Resolving with the number of widgets in the sidebar.
 */
function getSidebarWidgetCount( sidebarId ) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    wp.customize( 'sidebars_widgets[' + sidebarId + ']', function( sidebarSetting ) {
        deferred.resolve( sidebarSetting.get().length );
    } );
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Usage:

```
getSidebarWidgetCount( 'sidebar-1' ).done( function( count ){
    console.info( count );
} );
```